# Running a bash script from Notepadqq is not working

Tags: bash, shell

I try to include a bash script in notepadqq to run a build script for pandoc. I tried to add it in the menu but it isnt opening a gnome-terminal as expected it does nothing at all.

I already tried to launch the exact same code from another terminal and it is working so i guess my command is correct. I also tried to change the %directory% variable to the absolute path of the script but that wasnt working too. Even running a simple "hello world" from the shell seems not to be working.

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal --working-directory="%directory%" -e 'bash build.sh
```

what i also tried:

```
/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -e 'echo "hello world"'
```

with no result at all.

Normally it should open a new instace of gnome terminal run the script and so update my pdf but it is doing nothing at all.

Comment: Are you sure it's not doing anything at all?  Try something like this: `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'build.sh | less'`.

Comment: And your second example should be `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal -x bash -c 'echo "hello world"; sleep 10'` to make it show what happens.

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, i already configured my terminal to don't close when finishing a program but I tried your code but still no reaction. Am I doing something completly wrong? I add the script in the menu under run -> edit commands and then I press on the name in the run section after I copied the command and gave it a name right?